# Aligning columns under a \multicolumn

Tags: tables, siunitx, multicolumn

*Edit: Modified the MWE and tried to give a better description of my problem*

I'd like to be able to align columns under a multicolumn column header.

In the MWE I've just the data in the first table, and it appears how I expect it too, in the second table I've added a long column header.

I'd like to be able to modify the final two columns, such that the vertical divider appears midway through the "Very Long Column Name", and the final column in the last row does not get pushed into the center of the column.

This is the current output of the MWE
[image: This is the current output of the MWE]

While this is what I'm after...
[image: While this is what I'm after...]

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l c l|l}
    Row 1 & & a  & b \\
    Row 2 & & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{1.2} & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{3.4} \\
  \end{tabular} \\

  \begin{tabular}{l c l|l}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column Name} & \phantom{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Very Long Column Name} \\
    Row 1 & & a  & b \\
    Row 2 & & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{1.2} & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{3.4} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are line breaks allowed in the string "Very Long Column Name", or must the combined column be at least as wide as this string? Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How is  `\tablenum` defined?

Comment: @Mico, I cannot add line breaks the column names.

Comment: @Bernard, `\tablenum` comes from the siunitx package, it's not mine.

Comment: What does "cannot" mean here? Do you mean "want not", or do you mean to say that you don't know how to insert line breaks?

Comment: @Mico, Some of the column names in my document are images, so cannot be line broken.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. It would be really helpful if you edited your posting and described both your document setup and the image-related issues in greater detail. Maybe somebody else will be able to help you.

Comment: @Andy: I see. Never used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the second `tabular` here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l c l|l}
        Row 1 & & a  & b \\
        Row 2 & & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{1.2} & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{3.4} \\
    \end{tabular} \\

    \begin{tabular}{l c}
        Column Name & Very Long Column Name \\
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            Row 1\\
            Row 2\\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r|l@{}}
             a  & b \\
            \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{1.2} & \tablenum[table-format = 1.1]{3.4} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Changing the `@{}r|l@{}` to `@{}l|l@{}` gives me exactly what I'm after!